# How to set up Maintenance page for next js application hosted on server without having to redeploy next js code

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Anyone know an implementation of a Maintenance page similar to this enter image description here for a next.js application that wont require changing .env variables and redeploying each time site is switched on and off?

I am posted this question because someone not answer the previous questioin

Comment: I've posted my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754867